# Calculus exercise - differentiability and $C^1$ functions

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the function $f(x,y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{0}$, but is not of $C^1$ in any neighbourhood of $\mathbf{0}$

So a function is differentiable at $\mathbf{0}$ if $\lim\limits_{\mathbf{h} \to 0} \dfrac{f(\mathbf{0} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{0}) - Df(\mathbf{0})\mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h}|} =0$

So I did  $\lim\limits_{\mathbf{h} \to 0} \dfrac{f(\mathbf{h}) - Df(\mathbf{0})\mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h}|} =0$

Here I am completely stuck, I have no idea how to evaluate the matrix $Df(\mathbf{0})$, so I can't handle the limit. The book uses a different approach, it argues that $Df(\mathbf{0})$ is $0$ (which makes the algebra a lot easier) and they used the alternative limit quotient where no $\mathbf{h}$ appears, but such a quotient is never even mentioned in my book

**EDIT1**. At some point the book utilizes $|xy| \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2 +y^2)$. This resembles the AM_GM inequality or is this something else? Or was there some other Lemma that gives rise to this inequality?

**EDIT2**: I want to mention that I handled the last part of the question already, that is showing it is not $C^1$ in any neighbourhood of $\mathbf{0}$. I just computed $f_x(x,y)$ from first principle and concluded the limit does not even exist. The book chose to look at the limit of $f_x(x,y)$ an interval of $0$ - particular $(0,y)$, but I don't think that's necessary

Comment: Hint: $Df(0)=0$.

Comment: @julien, okay but why? That is the nature of the question

Comment: I understood the question. I just gave you a hint, since you had no clue about $Df(0)$. What do you have to prove, knowing that $Df(0)=0$? Hint 2: $|xy|\leq x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Recall that the partial derivative for $x$ (and for $y$ is computed by: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x} = 0$$

Comment: @julien, no that is my question *I don't know that $Df(0) = 0$*. You pointed out an inequity which I forgot to include in my question. Thanks

Comment: Also you limit should probably be $\frac{\cdots}{|\bf h|}$, as dividing by a vector is not a defined operation.

Comment: Let's try to state that way: prove $Df(0)=0$ using the second hint I gave you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes thanks for catching that

Comment: So $Df(\mathbf{0})$ here is a 2 by 1 matrix? If so what does $f$ look like in matrix form?

Comment: @julien, I know you are leading me to the following inequality $$0 \leq \frac{|xy|}{x^2 + y^2} \leq 1$$

Comment: Okay I resolved the issue with the matrix $Df(0)$. Now I am pondering over how $|xy| leq x^2 + y^2$ came about

Comment: For small enough $\bf h$ you have $f({\bf h})\leq|\bf h|^2\leq|h|$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your second inequality is not enough to prove the result. You need to use your first inequality, which of course holds for every $h$ but you know that.

Comment: @julien: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Just saying that if you use your second inequality $|f(h)|\leq |h|$, all you can do is prove that $\limsup |f(h)|/|h|\leq 1$. We really need $|f(h)|\leq |h|^2$ for our purpose here. So I am not sure why you added the second inequality in your comment.

Comment: @julien: Because the limit has $|\bf h|$ in the denominator. And we can use the second inequality to prove the conclusion **because** the first inequality is also true. I am agreeing with you, I am just pointing that out in a way I think is relevant to the presentation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I still don't follow you even with bold characters. How can you use the second inequality to prove the conclusion?

Comment: @julien: You don't use the second directly. You use the fact that the first one holds *and* the second one holds. No one said anything about using *only* the second. However the limit does not have $|{\bf h}|^2$, and we need a reasonable reason why we can transition from a number to its square.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok, I give up. Take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume we work with the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Recall the inequality $2|xy|\leq x^2+y^2$ which holds for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. This follows by developing the obvious inequality $(|x|-|y|)^2\geq 0$. Note that $|xy|\leq x^2+y^2$ would be sufficient to prove our claim below.

So for all $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, we have
$$
\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\|(x,y)\|}=\frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}=\frac{\|(x,y)\|}{2}.
$$

Let $L$ denote the null linear map $L(x,y)=0$.
The inequality above shows that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\|(x,y)\|}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{|f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)|}{\|(x,y)\|}=0.
$$

By definition, this proves that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with derivative $Df(0)=L=0$.

Note: the strategy here is to find a candidate for $Df(0)$, and then to check it satisfies the definition of differentiability. If you can't see what $Df(0)$ is gonna be, you can't get started.

Since you say you handled the last part, I'll stop here.